# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, associations

I have an app where user signs up with an email (Devise) or Omniauth which is working fine. I added a method to create a profile after the user sign up. Also in the views I want to have user info and profile info in the same page. I am not sure if I did the associations incorrectly or in my controllers but I get this error:

This is the error I am getting:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#edit
Couldn't find Profile with id=25
Extracted source (around line #58): @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
```

These are the models I am using:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_profile
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

  private
  def create_profile
    Profile.create(user: self)
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And this is the Profiles controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile #there was nothing before
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @profile = current_user.profile #there was nothing before
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to profiles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :headline)
    end
end
```

And the views:

```
<!-- views/profiles/_form.html.erb -->

<%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>
    <%= f.input :headline %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<!-- views/layouts/navigation.html.erb -->
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">Hello <a href="#" class="navbar-link"><%= @user.name %></a>!</p>
<% end %>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Sign in with your Email', new_user_session_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></li>
<% end %>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
<% end %>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_profile_path(@user) %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit settings', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know If there is something wrong in my code or how to fix the problem I am having. Also, if there is something else I should put here from my code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you exactly want in edit action, profile of current user or you want to search profile by its id?

Comment: I want to be able to edit the profile of the current user `params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :headline)
` and I have everything like this and can't seem to understand where the error is.

Comment: @RSB I tried what you said, and it worked! Thanks, but the other problem is still there, I get a nil when I call a Users profile, even though I can edit it...

Comment: I didn't get you sorry, can you explain it in details?

Comment: @RSB Sorry, I did what you said about the edit method and removing the `:edit` from the `set_profile` which fixed the problem. After I sign up I can go and edit the profile. The problem is that when I try to access the users profile in console like `u = User.last u.profile` I get `nil` So profile doesn't exist.

Comment: It's because for that particular user profile doesn't exist, you can check it in console by typing this command, `User.last.profile.present?`. It will return true or false

Comment: Or may be you need to restart the console, `ctrl+d` then again run `rails c`

Comment: @RSB Ok I get that, I am just so confused why I can edit the profiles, update, and the data is being saved, and when I check if profile exists using `User.last.profile.present?` I get `nil`

Comment: It should return `true` or `false` and not `nil`

Comment: Anyways, please accept the answer if you found it helpful

Comment: Sorry, I meant `false` :S and ok thanks for the help.

Comment: It returned false means no profile exists for that user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to handle the error when profile of current user is missing in database

```
def edit
  unless current_user.profile.blank?
    @profile = current_user.profile
  else
    flash[:notice] = "No profile exists for current user"
    redirect_to root_path
  end 
end
```

You anyway want profile for current user so you should better remove `before_filter :set_profile` for `edit` action

Answer (score 0):

It seems like at the first time you do not have the user profile so in the edit action

```
def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile #there was nothing before
  end

def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

there is no profile for the current user please check in the data base after creating a fresh user record. If a new profile record is creating or not.

try to change the after create method like this .

def create_profile
    create_profile.create!()
  end
There may be validation error.

Comment: I think it is being created, this is what I get in the console:
`SQL (167.1ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 02 Apr 201
4 05:22:38 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 02 Apr 2014 05:22:38 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 26]]`                                                  
`(83.3ms)  COMMIT`

Comment: @crentist Please check in the database and let me know.

Comment: Ok I did: `u = User.last` and then `u.profile` and got `Profile Load (242.7ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]`
`=> nil `

Comment: Yes that means no profile is created after creating the user.

Comment: The why does the console say it is inserting a profile in the db? I did what @RSB said to do and the error is gone! After sign up I can go and edit current user profile, but I still get nil in console!

Comment: Check my updated answer. for the after create method and let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: @crentist inserting means it's trying to insert but only after commit it will be saved in the database.